# EF6 Cannot insert duplicate key - I cannot find cause of this exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, thread-safety

I've got problem when I am trying to use method `AddTimeSeriesDefinition(TimeSeries series)` or `AddTimeSeriesMetaData(TimeSeriesMetaData tsData)` inside `Parallel.ForEach()`

I am struggling with this for couple of hours and I cannot believe that I cannot find any solution or even theoretical cause.

Inside my class `Data` which contains my db context `DBEntity db = new DBEntity()` I've got `AddTimeSeriesDefinition(TimeSeries series)` and `AddTimeSeriesMetaData()` methods :

```
public class Data : IDisposable 
{
    private DBEntity db;

    public Data()
    {
         db = new DBEntity();
    }      

    public TimeSeries AddTimeSeriesDefinition(TimeSeries series)
    {
        var timeSeries = db.TimeSeries.Where(ts => ts.Key1 == series.Key1 )
                                      .Where(ts => ts.Key2 == series.Key2 )
                                      .Where(ts => ts.Key3 == series.Key3 )
                                      .FirstOrDefault();
        if ( timeSeries == null )
        {
             timeSeries = db.TimeSeries.Add(series);
             db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return timeSeries;
    }

    public void AddTimeSeriesMetaData(TimeSeriesMetaData tsData)
    {
        var tsd = db.TimeSeriesMetaData.Where(ts => ts.Key1 == tsData.Key1 )
                                       .Where(ts => ts.Key2== tsData.Key2)
                                       .FirstOrDefault();

        if (tsd == null)
            db.TimeSeriesMetaData.Add(tsData);
        else
            tsd.Value = tsData.Value;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error($"Error occurred (...) Key1:{tsData.Key1} Key2:{tsData.Key2}", ex);
        }
    }


    Dispose()
    {...}
}
```

However when I am using them in my main class, for example :

```
private MainClass
{
    Data DB { get { value = new Data() } }

    ...

    Parallel.ForEach( // arguments )
    {
        ...
        using( var db = DB ) 
        {
             db.AddTimeSeriesDefinition(timeSeries);  
        } 
        ...
    }

}
```

it's sometimes, totally randomly crashing in line

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

with exception :

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TimeSeriesMetaDatas'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TimeSeriesMetaData'. The duplicate key value is ("Key1", "Key2"). The statement has been terminated.
```

For example my `TimeSeriesMetaData` EF class:

```
[Table("TimeSeriesMetaData")]
public partial class TimeSeriesMetaData
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Key1 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Key2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Key3 { get; set; }
}
```

I've read that creating `Entity Framework` `DBContext` each time for each operation should be also Thread-safe. 
What can be cause of this problem if I've always checked if record exist?

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that DbSet is not ThreadSafe. You are having a run condition withing your Parallel.ForEach loop. You have to lock your call to both of your methods. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I think that was solution, to add lock(){} in those methods. 
It seems to working now without any issues as far I was able to test in 1 hour.